# Prove that $a_n$ = $2^n$ + $(-1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I am given the sequence $a_0= 2$, $a_1= 1$ and $a_{n+2}= a_{n+1} + 2a_n$

How do I prove that $a_n$ = $2^n + (-1)^n$

Comment: Use induction...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** When proving that a sequence defined recursively is equal to some closed formula, you only need to verify that the closed formula obeys (1) the base case and (2) the recursion.  Then you are done, by induction.  So,

1. Check that $2^n + (-1)^n$ gives the right value in the base cases $a_0 = 2$ and $a_1 = 1$.
2. Check that $2^n + (-1)^n$ satisfies $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + 2a_n$.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @JiK I believe I am being hate-downvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

Guess $a_n = c^n$, then $$ c^{n+2} = c^{n+1} + 2 c^n \implies c^2 - c - 2 = 0 \implies (c-2)(c+1) = 0 \implies c=2,-1$$

$$ \therefore a_n = A2^n + B (-1)^n$$

$$ a_0 = A + B = 2, \; \; a_1 = 2A -B = 1 \implies A=B=1$$

$$ \therefore a_n = 2^n + (-1)^n $$

Comment: This is not a proof.

Comment: prove to me that this is not a proof.

Comment: "Guess $a_n = c^n$" You presented a good way of guessing what $a_n$ would be in the first place, but you did not prove your formula in the end.  Your answer assumes that $a_n$ is a linear combination of two exponential functions.

Comment: this is not a proof.

Comment: I assume you meant to post that on my answer?

Comment: You "guessed" $a_n=c^n$ but then wrote $a_n$ as a *linear combination* of exponentials.